# Install pip in Travis virtualenv

Tags: python-3.x, pip, travis-ci

I have a Python 3 project with a pytest suite, and want to run it on Travis.

I'm trying to write a `test.sh` script that can work both on the developer machine and Travis CI as well, which has to setup the virtualenv, install the packages, run pytest and then destroy the virtualenv. I can't use Tox because it doesn't follow dependency links, which we are using.

The script (simplified) is:

```
python3 -m venv .venv
pip install -e . --process-dependency-links --allow-all-external
.venv/bin/pip install pytest
.venv/bin/pytest
rm -rf .venv
```

on my machine it works, but on Travis this fails because inside the `.venv/bin` there is no `pip` executable, nor `pip2` or `pip3`.

I tried to enforce the installation of it with `.venv/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` but still there's no binary.

Running `python3 -m venv --help` I see there's an optional flag `--without-pip` available, and the same help text says that `pip is bootstrapped by default`. How can I ensure that pip is present in a virtualenv?

EDIT: a likely solution is to use `python3 -m pip install pytest` to install the pytest package instead of invoking `pip` as a command directly

Comment: Have you "activated" the virtual environment? See the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/venv.html#creating-virtual-environments). Can you share the full error log?

Comment: On passing explicitly path to executable you won't have to activate virtual environment. It needs specifying it though and installing pip first (it's not in standard python installation), which I do not see here.

Comment: Currently I "solved" by using a different script for travis that install everything without virtualenv. By checking the `TRAVIS` environment variable I prevent the user to accidentally run it locally and install stuff on the system. Still, it's a workaround that requires to have two scripts to maintain